# Need to find Background Image of Magento site?

Tags: html, css, image, magento

see the background Grid , on this site hxxp://www.solarpowergetics.com/ It is a Magento website ,How can I get that image or is that CSS

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's CSS. Looking at the source, it's an image that is repeating. Each div has a partially transparent background that would make the lattice appear to be fading towards the center.

Try Right-Click and Inspect element in the future and navigate to the `body` or `html` element. Usually your answer will be there

Comment: Is there any way ,I can get it on my other website ,I want the same grid background hxxp://www.chaldean-catholic.org/

Comment: You can, but without permission, it's basically considered stealing. Using the inspector you can find the following code in the body element: `background-image: url(../images/pattern24.png);` which will bring you to the image. Your best bet (if you dont have permission to use it) is to recreate a similar image on your own

Comment: Thanks Mark ,I got it ,Both are my sites

Answer (score 0):

A background will always be applied via CSS (well or inline HTML styling). Best thing to do is to open up the developer toolbar (Ctrl + I for Windows or Alt + Cmd + I for OS X) and look for the html or body tag in the HTML. Click on either and it'll bring up the CSS. Then you just need to look for the background property and that will either provide you with a colour like...

```
background: #ffffff;
```

Or if an image is used, it'll probably look something like...

```
background: url(myimage.png);
```

There are many different variations depending on what they want the background to look like. If an image is used, right click or control click to open it in a new tab. Browsers like Chome will make the image link and active url so you can actually visit it and see the real image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any way ,I can get it on my other website ,I want the same grid background hxxp://www.chaldean-catholic.org/

Comment: If you have permission to do so from the person(s) that own that website, find the image, so go to the (ie. http://example.com/image.png) and save it to your computer. Then upload the image to where your websites files are hosted and amend your CSS to accommodate the image like I described above.

Comment: Yes ,I have access to the site files but is there any way I can find name of the image on the website itself via inspect element or  firebug

Comment: Yep, like I said, open up the developer toolbar and you should have some CSS down the right hand side of your browser screen. The link to images should be blue. Do you know what browser you are using? I use Google Chrome, this is what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/HJWoFH9.jpg In the picture I have highlighted the body tag and the CSS along with the background property has been shown with the image name which has been made into a link. Click on the link and save the image.